# Oracle DateAdd() of 2 different columns

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to figure out a DateAdd() equivalent in Oracle that is actually the difference in seconds between 2 columns in the same table:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT p.packet_id,
    p.launch_dt,
    r.route_duration,
    s.completion_date,
    DATEADD(SS, r.route_duration, p.launch_dt) AS tempDate
FROM 
    tdc_arc_apprpkt_def p
    JOIN tdc_arc_inpr_route_def r
        ON p.packet_id = r.packet_id
    JOIN tdc_arc_inpr_route_step_detai s
        ON p.packet_id = s.packet_id
        AND s.completion_date > DATEADD(SS, r.route_duration, p.launch_dt)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to being able to do date arithmetic using fractions of days as Tony demonstrates, assuming you are using 9i or later, you can also use interval functions (or, even better, define the `ROUTE_DURATION` column as an interval) and add intervals to dates.  In your case, you can do

```
p.launch_dt + numtodsinterval( r.route_duration, 'SECOND' )
```

to add `route_duration` seconds to `launch_dt`.

If you were to define the `route_duration` column as an `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` rather than a `NUMBER`, you could simply add it to a date

```
p.launch_dt + r.route_duration
```

Comment: Thank you, we are going to convert that column to an interval of number of seconds so this works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to add `r.route_duration` seconds to `p.launch_dt`?  In that case the expression is:

```
p.launch_dt + (r.route_duration/24/60/60)
```

Oracle DATE arithmetic works in days, so the divisions by 24, 60 and 60 convert the route_duration value from seconds to days.